# During build, on what basis does docker decide whether to create a new layer or use an existing layer?

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-build

The docker file has various command like FROM, RUN, etc. Each of this command creates a layer (intermediary image).

During build, assuming the layer already exists, on what basis does docker decide whether to create a new layer or use an existing layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `docker build` caching system is pretty simple.  For most commands, if the previous layer was cached, and there is a layer that runs the exact same command (`RUN`, `ENV`, `CMD`, ...) then it reuses the cached layer, and repeats this check for the next command.  For `COPY` and `ADD` commands the decision is based on a hash of the file contents.

This is detailed in [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache) in the Docker documentation.

Practically, there are a couple of things this means:

- You almost never need `docker build --no-cache`, since if the Dockerfile or any involved files have changed, the cache will be automatically invalidated.
- If you have an expensive step to install dependencies (`npm install`, `pip install`, `bundle install`, ...) have a first step that only `COPY`s the files that list the dependencies, then `RUN whatever install`, then `COPY` the rest of your application.  This avoids invalidating the cache for the "install" step if only application code has changed.
- If you have a Debian- or Ubuntu-based image, `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install` in a single command.  This avoids a problem where the URLs from the "update" step are cached, but the packages in the "install" step change, and the cached URLs are no longer valid.

Comment: For the expensive install step, assuming I have RUN packagename, then on the subsequent run of the build, will docker use the cached image or will it run the command so it can download latest package version? (assuming the new version for packagename is available in nuget).

Comment: If the command is literally `RUN packagename`, and neither that command text nor anything before it in the Dockerfile has changed, it will use the cached version.  (Corollary: if the command is `RUN git clone ...`, it will not pull a newer version of code from a remote repository on rebuild.)

Comment: But if you have something like a requirements file or a package version lock file, and the version number there changes, the `COPY` step that copies it in will invalidate the cache, and the `RUN whatever install` will get repeated.

Comment: ADD command is preceded by ENV that sets environment variable with dynamic value {value} cmd line argument. The ENV, ADD and RUN command that follow dont use cache.

Comment: `ENV` can invalidate the cache too, particularly if the value changes.

Comment: It seems to invalidate even if the value is unchanged.

Comment: David- can you tell me if every occurrence of FROM (in dockerfile) creates a new image independent of any previous layers? That is-  FROM always creates a new image (can use base layer from cache).

Comment: Each `FROM` line "starts over".  It doesn't create a new layer or image, but points at which ever image you're starting `FROM`.  The caching is considered independently for each build stage.